# When adding `#![no_std]` to a library, are there any disadvantages or complications for the users of that library?

Tags: rust

I wrote a Rust library. I heard about the `no_std` feature and noticed that my library does not use anything from `std` that isn't offered by [`core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/index.html) and [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/index.html). So in theory I could just add the `#![no_std]` attribute and change a few imports.

But I wonder how this influences the users of my library. Of course, my hope is that by using `#![no_std]`, users in `no_std` environments can use my crate as well. That's good, of course. But: **do users of my library have any disadvantage from my library being `no_std`?** For example, are they forced to also use `#![no_std]`? That would be bad. I wonder because most crates hide `no_std` compatibility behind a Cargo feature. And I actually couldn't find anything about this question online.

If there are no disadvantages from using `#![no_std]`, then every crate who *can* work without `std` should add that attribute, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> For example, are they forced to also use `#![no_std]`?

Not at all. The dependent crate (that is, the crate/project which will consume your crate) will know to find the `core` crate required by your dependency, and one will be free to use it as if `no_std` was ever involved. The main difference comes from what to expect from this dependency and how many other crates can use it. In other words, the set of crates compatible with your dependency should always be a superset if that dependency is prepared for `no_std`.

The [readme of KodrAus/rust-nostd](https://github.com/KodrAus/rust-no-std), an example of using and testing `no_std` in a library, also recommends using `no_std` whenever possible for maximum compatibility:

> The current design of Rust's standard library is split into a few layers, each building on the assumed platform capabilities of the one below. There's:
>
> - `std`: the full standard library assumes the presence of threads, a filesystem, and networking. [...]
> - `alloc`: the collections layer builds on the core by assuming runtime support for dynamic memory allocation.
> - `core`: the core layer makes no (well, not very many) assumptions about the > underlying platform. Just about any target that can run Rust code is supported by core.
>
> So when you're designing your library you can make it maximally portable by **targeting the lowest layer of the standard library that you can**.

The reason some crates put `no_std` behind a Cargo feature is because the crate may contain some opt-in functionalities which do require `std`, or at the very least `alloc`. By conditioning on Cargo features, environments without the standard library can still use the crate, whereas those with `std` or `alloc` can use an extended API of the crate. An example of "lib.rs" that shows this capability can be seen below.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
extern crate core;

#[cfg(feature = "alloc")]
extern crate alloc;

pub fn foo_into_slice(slice: &mut [u8]) { unimplemented!() }

/// Vec requires alloc
#[cfg(feature = "alloc")]
use alloc::vec::Vec;

#[cfg(feature = "alloc")]
pub fn foo_into_vec(vec: &mut Vec<u8>) { unimplemented!() }
```

Comment: It's probably just me, but I really don't understand the first paragraph :/ I think I am mostly confused by the use of "[this/your] dependency". By that you are referring to my crate, yes? And "the consuming crate" is the user of my crate, yes? Ah and the "should" in the last sentence is meant as "to my knowledge it is" and not "it has to be", right?

Comment: That is indeed what I meant, @LukasKalbertodt. I rephrased things a bit nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks! :) So just to be super clear: adding `#![no_std]` to my crate will (most certainly) not have any disadvantages, so I should do it, yes?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt The only one that comes to mind would be the chance of your crate one day requiring something from one layer upwards, requiring a breaking change and a semver major version bump.